# Reference to external file problem with changed path to xlsx also when it's closed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help me solve very weird problem from a long time. Believe me I spend months around research about it here and tones other websites, forums, everything and it not help. I'll try to describe a problem:

- I have one main file where according to the value from cell looking for some data in external xlsx file.
- Both files are saved in the same folder
- Only filename for external xlsx file can be different, according to the user (in this example PL.xlsx)

In main file I have like below - this part works good but the problem is filename which I need to change according to situation (user):

`=LEFT( INDEX( 'C:\Users\username\Documents\project\analysis\PL.xlsx'!Row_CompanyName,, MATCH( E7, 'C:\Users\username\Documents\project\analysis\PL.xlsx'!Row_SystemCode, 0 ) ),60 )`

Cell E7 contain System Code which I am looking for in external file PL.xlsx e.g. "E1234"
In external workbook PL.xlsx row 2:2 is named as "Row_CompanyName" where is my result to take - Company Name, and in row 3:3 all the codes searched by MATCH to take a column number.
LEFT is used here to take only max 60 characters Company Name if it is so long (doesn't matter in this problem).

Everything is fine here when external PL.xlsx file is opened or closed. I mean the part in INDEX and MATCH is different according to situation PL.xlsx file is open or not (automatically by Excel where full path is included or not) as below:
When file is open:
`PL.xlsx!Row_CompanyName,,`
After closing:
`'C:\Users\username\Documents\project\analysis\PL.xlsx'!Row_CompanyName,,`

When I try methods to make dynamic filename problem appear. For example in cell A1 I have filename like PL, ES, UK, etc. for now it is "PL"

After changing code and use INDIRECT which I thought is good for these situation it not works:

`=LEFT( INDEX( INDIRECT("'"&Main_Path&"\PL.xlsx'!Row_CompanyName"),, MATCH( E7, INDIRECT("'"&SETS_GSR_Path&"\PL.xlsx'!Row_SystemCode"), 0 ) ),60 )`

Main_Path is a Name of cell with generated by simple formula path as text below:
`'C:\Users\username\Documents\project\analysis\PL.xlsx'!Row_SystemCode`
This is needed because sometimes PL can be as another country ES, UK, PL, etc.
It works fine to the moment when file PL.xlsx is opened, after close - #REF! error for MATCH

Trying every combination with brackets, without, adding ' or " - nothing help.

Why Excel so amazing application have a problem with simple path and use it in functions and of course external files? Maybe there is another way in formulas?
Of course I know, I can use VBA known by me as well but in this situation it is not proper way for small automation.

Please help :)
Thank you in advance.
Dawid

Please help with functions and external files problem, related to dynamic path which can be changed and/or filename of external file. I try almost everything what I found in Google, here and many other sites.

Comment: `INDIRECT` only works when the external workbook is open. You're basically out of luck. There are some (not necessarily clean) workarounds. VBA may be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought in this area. Whole night researching and nothing. Actually I will discuss those problem with team. Maybe it is possible they have open just one related file e.g. PL.xlsx or I just create VBA for it. Maybe smart function here will resolve problem and it can be still dynamic. I am not sure how VBA communicate external files from main workbook. If situation repeat probably we decide to not use Excel for it, just normal application and C++ or worse scenario - php which is the easiest form but required to be online. Eventually just migration data between workbooks.

Comment: Additional info. Okay external file work to the moment only when path is static not created but something or taken from any cell. e.g. drive W ('W:\TeamData\...\[PL.xlsx]Sheet1'!$1:$1) so I just decided to consolidate data in one file for all teams and be fine. I think this is not a problem with Excel or functions, it's just a bug never resolved by m$oft.But why it works good in Office 365 for Apple, Big question? I think m$oft just ignored problem for many years. Google Sheets solve it long time ago so why not m$oft? Many waysit is escalated and nothing. So nice app and simple thing not works